# CanvasRenderingContext2D градиент до кривой

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas, графика, 2d

Имеются 2 линии: прямая и кривая.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли сделать градиент от первой (красной) до второй (синей) линии, используя canvas 2d context?

Пример НЕ правильного градиента (так как должен достигаться синий цвет на всей протяженности кривой.

```
    const grd = context.createLinearGradient(0, canvas.height / 2, 0, 200);
    grd.addColorStop(0, "red");
    grd.addColorStop(1, "blue");
    context.fillStyle = grd;

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(50, canvas.height / 2);
    context.quadraticCurveTo(750, 150, canvas.width - 50, canvas.height / 2);
    context.fill();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD: Дополнение для @Grundy

Вот что я стремлюсь получить:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С тем отличием, что сверху может быть кривая линяя, а не прямая.
Такой результат я получаю, отрисовывая множество отдельных градиентов. Есть ли возможность получить что-то похожее другим, более "правильным"  способом, потому что для кривой возникнут трудности сделать что-то подобное.

```
    for (let i = 1; i < 300; i++) {
        const grd = context.createLinearGradient(0, canvas.height / 2, 0, canvas.height / 2 - i);
        grd.addColorStop(0, "red");
        grd.addColorStop(1, "blue");
        context.fillStyle = grd;
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(50 + i * 2, canvas.height / 2);
        context.lineTo(50 + i * 2, canvas.height / 2 - i);
        context.lineTo(50 + (i + 1) * 2, canvas.height / 2 - (i + 1));
        context.lineTo(50 + (i + 1) * 2, canvas.height / 2);
        context.fill();
    }
```

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста Ваш код

Comment: Так у меня есть только 2 линии) Весь вопрос и состоит в том, как создать правильный градиент (если такое возможно).

Comment: какой именно должен быть градиент? Какое направление?

Comment: добавь код, как ты рисуешь линии

Comment: В данном примере он должен начинаться от красной линии и иметь красный цвет и заканчивать на синей линии, имея синий цвет. Если использовать обычный линейный градиент от красной линии, до верхней точки синей линии, то получим, что во всех точках, кроме верхней, мы не получим синий цвет, а какой-то промежуточный. Мне необходимо, чтоб градиент заканчивался в каждой соотвествующей точке кривой

Comment: А можешь на картинке показать какой результат ожидается? Возможно поможет другой тип градиентов конический либо радиальный

Comment: Вроде бы, конечно, я постарался подробно описать, что стремлюсь получить, но все же добавил картинку с результатом для одного из случаев.

Comment: Не, пример с прямой - не походит - он делается просто сменой начальной точки градиента. С кривой линией уде так не получится